# Hyperledger Fabric Composer-Rest-Server how to setup a Username / Password Authentication?

Tags: passport.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

First of all, I am very new to hyperledger and probably I am thinking wrong at some place.

Right now, I am working on an application that I am doing with Hyperledger Fabric, Hyperledger Composer and hyperledger-rest-server.

Now I read a bit about the authentication process but I got stuck at one point.

Before I get to my questions, I tell you a bit more about what I want:

I want to create a frontend application with angular where the user can log in with his username/password.

What I read is that I can use Passport.js for hyperledger-rest-server authentication. But what I understood, is that this is for authentication with third parties like twitter, facebook etc.

My Questions:

- Is my thinking correct here?
- Is this possible?
- How can I do this?
- Is it also possible for the user to change his password?
- With Passport.js, how does the administrator define what Facebook Account, for example, is for which account? I mean hyperledger needs to know that my Facebook Account belongs to my Hyperledger Fabric Account.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is one such option and completely feasible. You can use `passportjs` with `composer-rest-server` and link a `username` to a unique `composer business card`. This way when the user logs in, it gets a token from the server. Every subsequent API call must have the token, based on this the rest server will use the required `composer card`

You would first need to [follow this](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/integrating/getting-started-rest-api) and setup your server using `composer-rest-server -c ADMIN_CARD_NAME`. You will then need to activate authentication for the server. Go to http://0.0.0.0:3000/explorer to view the APIs including those for authentication.

Based on the authentication method you would need to install the required package. [This tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/gangachris125/passport-jwt-authentication-for-hyperledger-composer-rest-server-jqfgkoljn) is a great place to start. Using the `wallet import` endpoint, the admin can map a Facebook account or a username to a particular `composer card`.

Now my honest opinion is, `composer-rest-server` is not suitable for a pilot/ production rollout. I have used this and ultimately decided to handle my own APIs and authentication.

1. Create a participant and import the identity

```
async function createParticipant() {
    const businessNetworkConnection = new BusinessNetworkConnection();
    await businessNetworkConnection.connect(adminCardName);
    let registry=  await businessNetworkConnection.getParticipantRegistry(`${BASE_NS}.SampleUser`);
    const factory = businessNetworkConnection.getBusinessNetwork().getFactory();
    let user= factory.newResource(BASE_NS, 'SampleUser', 'username123');
    await businessNetworkConnection.save(user);
    // User is registered, time to import an identity
    let creds = await businessNetworkConnection.issueIdentity(`${BASE_NS}.SampleUser#username123`, 'username123);
    const adminConnection = new AdminConnection();
    await adminConnection.connect(adminCardName);
    const card = new IdCard({
        userName: creds.userID,
        version: 1,
        enrollmentSecret: creds.userSecret,
        businessNetwork: businessName
      }, connectionProfile);
    await adminConnection.importCard(`username123@my-network`, card);
    await adminConnection.disconnect();
    await businessNetworkConnection.disconnect();
}
```

2. Use your own DB to store a username and password for a user. Map it to the `composer card`. For this example I have used mongoDB. The schema would be something like this

```
let newUser = new userSchema({
      username: 'Alice,
      password: 'topSecretPassword,
      emailId: 'foo@bar.com',
      participantId: 'username123,
      composerCard: `username123@my-network`
});
```

3. The middleware (most important). So when Alice logs in, the system will return a `jsonwebtoken` that she must use in all subsequent API calls.

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

app.post('/login', auth());
async function auth(req, res, next) {
    let username = req.body.username;
    let password = req.body.password;
    // User whatever authentication method you want here and return a jwt
    // In my project I created a new token db and kept a mapping
    const authToken = jwt.sign(tokenSeed, jwtSecret, { });
    const newToken = new tokenSchema({
      authToken: authToken,
      username: req.body.username
    });
    await newToken.save();
    res.send({ authToken: authToken, username: username });
}
```

4. The actual API call. So this is basically a middleware function that checks the token and decides which `composer card` to use for the transactions

```
const chooseCard = async (req, res, next) => {
    // Retrieve the token from the DB
    let token = await tokenSchema.findOne({ authToken: req.headers['x-access-token'] });
    // Get the user information
    let user = await userSchema.findOne({ username: token.username });
    let card = user.composerCard;
    req.composerCardToUse = card;
    next();
};

const someFancyTx = async (req, res, next) => {
    let card = req.composerCardToUse;
    await businessNetworkConnection.connect(card);
    // And the transactions submitted with this instance will use the required card


}

app.post('/sendMoney', chooseCard, somefancyTx);
```

NOTE: I have skipped a few validation steps (check authenticity of jwt, user session) and skipped some of the boilerplate code that would make this answer unnecessarily long. I have run a pilot and a PoC successfully using this same system.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Can you send me the github link of your PoC?

Comment: Well its private cause of an NDA with the company, but I took this code from my actual repository and sanitized it a bit. To give you a picture, we had about 200 participants use unique login IDs and composer cards over a month of testing and didn't face any issues.

Comment: Oh okay, I am now also working on a PoC. Maybe you can help me when I have problems :)

Comment: Ya sure, you can probably just comment over here at a later stage and I will get the notification. If its a PoC, I highly recommend not using `composer-rest-server`. It is useful for quick debugging and testing but not enough flexibility when it comes to building rich queries and allowing different auth techniques such as via an OTP, which I also have. If you able to get this working, request you to accept the answer. Good luck!

Comment: Okay, thank you. What's the alternative to composer-rest server? I mean how can I do transactions from a angular applications without an api?

Comment: No other way :). You have to write your own APIs using the SDK provided by composer and then call it from your angular application. Its time consuming process, but the most stable way imo.

Comment: Agrawal Hello I have a problem. I setup everything but when I start the composer-rest-server docker container I get an error. Do you have time for a quick teamviewer session to fix this? My email is: xbit.dany@gmail.com , you can write me there